# How to show user-friendly error page in browser when runtime exception is thrown by servlet?

Tags: jsp, jsf, facelets, custom-error-pages

I'm developing web-application with JSF. I tested it as I was able to but from time to time runtime exceptions are thrown.

So, how to redirect user to special error page every time an exception is thrown (instead of displaying 500 Error with full tomcat logs)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just declare an `<error-page>` in `web.xml` wherein you can specify the page which should be displayed on a certain [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) (or any of its subclasses) or a [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). E.g.

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

which will display the error page on any subclass of the `java.lang.Exception`, but thus not `java.lang.Throwable` or `java.lang.Error`. This way you can have your own error page for any kind of `Throwable`. E.g. `java.sql.SQLException`, `java.io.IOException` and so on.

Or,

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

which will display the error page on a HTTP 500 error, but you can also specify another ones for 404 (Page Not Found), 403 (Forbidden), etcetera.

If you declare `<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>` in top of `error.jsp`, then you have access to the thrown [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) (and thus also all of its getters) by `${exception}` in EL.

```xml
<p>Message: ${exception.message}</p>
```

Also see the [Java EE 5 tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html#bnaet).

Comment: What if I have a servlet rather than a jsp? Is there an equivalent for `isErrorPage="true"` ?

Comment: The equivalent for non-JSP is `request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION)`.

Answer (score 10):

In your web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/errorpages/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

You may also catch specific exceptions or exceptions which extend `Throwable`:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/errorpages/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    If you use java config in spring, you can follow,

   @Configuration
   public class ExcpConfig {

    @Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver= new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        resolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings); // None by default
        resolver.setExceptionAttribute("ErrorOccurred"); // Default is "exception"
        resolver.setDefaultErrorView("500"); // 500.jsp
        return r;
    }

}
```