# Exception doesn't get redirected to error-page when myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING is set to false

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, myfaces, servlet-3.0

I have implemented an error JSF page which gives basic information to users. It is triggered by the `<error-page>` tag in my `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

This works fine with a 404 error. In order to use it also for exceptions, I have disabled error handling by MyFaces 2.1.10 in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Handling+Server+Errors#HandlingServerErrors-Provideanerrorpage it says that an Exception should trigger a redirection to `/error`. However, when I throw a `RuntimeException` in my code, it shows in the logs but all the user gets is a blank page.

I can't seem to figure out why and how to get (if possible) the expected behaviour.

The application server is tomcat-7.0.35

Comment: You can find the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748220/how-to-show-user-friendly-error-page-instead-of-tomcat-log-with-stack-trace-in-b

Comment: Thank you for this link. However the error-page configuration is what I have (except I use the new possibility in servlet 3 to have a catch-all). Furthermore, I would rather not use JSP.

Comment: Are you sending an ajax request or not? If so, are you using an exception handler for it? Exceptions on ajax requests have by default indeed no form of feedback.

Comment: no ajax has been used at that point. I directly throw a RuntimeException from a bean accessor that is accessed from the JSF.

Comment: @Ravi , no, this has been corrected in 7.0.35 and if you read correctly, the error-page is indeed triggered for a 404.