# How to access HTTP response text in Tomcat error page

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using Tomcat 6 (but the same should apply to Tomcat 7). Let's say my `web.xml` contains this definition:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/Handle401Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Suppose I now return HTTP 401 from some other servlet/JSP:

```
httpResponse.sendError(SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "This is a message");
```

How can I access the HTTP response text ("This is a message") in `Handle401Error.jsp`? The way Tomcat does this, when it shows an error page like this

[image: Tomcat error page]

is by using a `Valve` (`ErrorReportValve`). Do I need to write a `Valve` as well?

Edit: the accepted answer below is exactly what I have been looking for, and the assumed duplicate of this question does not mention the same solution.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748220/how-to-show-user-friendly-error-page-in-browser-when-runtime-exception-is-thrown

Comment: No it's not, this has nothing to do with exceptions. I understand how to handle exceptions this way.

Comment: If you suggest throwing exceptions instead of returning HTTP code + message, yes, that sounds doable, and I might consider it if there is no direct way to do it. But it's still a hack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the message in a custom error page (Tomcat)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995248/how-to-get-the-message-in-a-custom-error-page-tomcat)

Comment: @kevcodez yes it seems to be a duplicate. Will investigate the other question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat stores the message string in an internal class `org.apache.coyote.Response`.

There is no standard way to access the message: From the javadoc of HttpServletResponse#sendError(int,String):

> If an error-page declaration has been made for the web application corresponding to the status code passed in, it will be served back in preference to the suggested msg parameter and **the msg parameter will be ignored**.

Poor API design.

As a workaround you could put the error message as attribute into the request, just call response.sendError(401) and in your error page extract the message from the request attributes:

In your code:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ...
HttpServletResponse response = ...
request.setAttribute("myerrormessage", "This is a message");
response.sendError(401);
```

In your error jsp page:

```
Message <%=request.getAttribute("myerrormessage")%>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to add an attribute to the response?

Comment: my fault, there are no attributes in ServletResponse, but only in ServletRequest (edited my answer accordingly)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works well. I am going to accept your answer, but just that you get more upvotes in the future - would you mind writing up some example code snippets? :)