# Get back to the default Tomcat error page on a redirected error page

Tags: java, jsp, http, tomcat

I am building a java web app using Tomcat.

Using something like this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

In the `web.xml`,  I redirect to a user-friendly error page, if the server respond with an error.

I also want to put a link on this user-friendly *error.jsp* page (name Technical Spec), so that when the user clicks it, he/she gets back to the original Tomcat error page.

Is it possible to achieve that ? If yes, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: why u want to do it?

Comment: to help tech staff in identifying the real tech problem with more details for example

Comment: i would rather suggest you to use `Exception` object in your`error.jsp` and use this object to `getMessage()` and `getStacktrace()` in your jsp page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible but you can still access the error/exception's tech details on the redirected page check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748220/how-to-show-user-friendly-error-page-in-browser-when-runtime-exception-is-thrown)
Where you'll find details on the below:

> If you declare `<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>` in top of error.jsp, then you have access to the thrown Exception (and thus also all of its getters) by `${exception}` in EL.