# Why does Tomee remove all my changes to web.xml in conf folder?

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

I'm trying to set a user friendly `404.html`. I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748220/how-to-show-user-friendly-error-page-in-browser-when-runtime-exception-is-thrown)

I added `<error-page>` tag to `web.xml` file that was in the `conf` folder `C: . . .\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4\conf\web.xml` as following

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/PageNotFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

However, when I start Tomee, it would rewrite this `web.xml` with all it's default values. As if I never made any changes. Why?

Comment: maybe it's a problem with catalina base vs catalina home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically error pages are deployed in the application, not at the server level. The web.xml at the server level defines the properties for the default servlet though, so *technically* that should work.

Are you starting the application from the command line or from your IDE? When I start it from the command line, your exact change stays in the web.xml. Sometimes your IDE can do funny things with your deployment descriptors if you're starting it from there.